# Styling dcc.Dropdown Component In A Dash App

Tags: python, html, reactjs, dropdown, plotly-dash

I'm having trouble figuring out how to vertically center the input text of a dcc.Dropdown component in my Dash app. The code for the dropdown is below.

```py
dcc.Dropdown(
    className = 'switchDeviceBeta4',
    id = 'selectDeviceDropdownButtonClicks',
    options = deviceList,
    placeholder = '',
    clearable = False,
    style = {
        'display': 'block',
        'width': '70%',
        'height': 100,
        'margin-top': '2%',
        'margin-left': '14%',
        'background-color': '#F6FBFF',
        'border-color': '#DFE6E9',
        'textAlign': 'center',
        'font-family': 'Arial',
        'font-size': '40px',
        'verticalAlign': 'middle',
        'justify-content': 'center',
    },   
),
```

I have tried using the verticalAlign and textAlign css commands both inline and with an external css style sheet, but haven't been able to figure it out. I am wondering if anyone has run into this problem and solved it before.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have expected Output?

Comment: So the output is just a dummy output as the input would change something in the sql database. I have this callback working fine, I just need to adjust the style to vertically align.